# Unable to share Stack Exchange links on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Since 12 hours ago, I noticed that Facebook disabled the little box that gives a preview of the site for the sharing of any Stack Exchange links in status messages - anyone knows why?

I have tried using Stack Exchange's 'Share' button but Facebook returns an Error 500.

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question for better clarity.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269147/21960